# How to define 2 separate filters on one Collection?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a collection which is appearing in 2 separate lists. One list should show all the items (unfiltered) and the second list should show the items which match a certain criterion (filtered).

The 2 list's ItemsSource Properties are bound to 2 Properties in the ViewModel.

I tried to set a DefaultView for the filtered list but it affects both lists.

```
ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_manager.Modules);
view.Filter = delegate(object item)
{
    Model.BaseModule bm = item as Model.BaseModule;
    if (bm != null)
    {
        return bm is TemplatedUnitOfTest && ((TemplatedUnitOfTest)bm).TemplateGuid == _uot.Header.Id;
    }
    return false;
};
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changinge the default view, explicitly create two separate instances of `ListCollectionView`, filter one, and bind each list to the relevant view.

An `ItemsControl` (or derivative) will always wrap its `Items` collection in a `CollectionView` before displaying *anyway* - if you do this step yourself then you have more control over what's displayed.